# Need to open permission to 766 to let PHP to edit files

Tags: php, apache, file-permissions

As the title described, I have tried making the file which I need to edit permission to 764 and it didn't work.
I don't have permission to the php config and other main configuration, do I have any options other than using 766?
Additionally, will 766 let other to edit my file over HTTP?

Comment: You shouldn't need executable permission in order to write a file.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth is right. You shouldn't have to set the execute to 7 to edit a file. Is the file you want to edit in the same apache directory? Apache usually runs as either the user group _apache_ or _www_, and it won't let PHP do much outside /var/www

Comment: Have you tried the above command addgroup www-data on the command prompt. Might need sudo access for this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the above command addgroup www-data on the command prompt. Might need sudo access for this to work?

The command is

```
sudo addgroup www-data
```

Try and see if it works. I must add, it is not recommended to use 777 as the setting. Find a way to handle that.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't have sudo access.